# Glassfish does not show my webservices

Tags: web-services, glassfish-4

I have a very simple webservice as follow:

```
package testSmart;
 import javax.jws.*;

@WebService
 public class Add {

@WebMethod
public int addElem(int i, int j){
    return i+j;
 }
}
```

Now when I use the following link:

```
http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf
```

But when I open it the Add webservice is not shown in the table:

[image]

Just for more explanation I am following the following video which does he same:

[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5cQkVgq6jE&index=10&list=PLJvZcvttEvnPKCvsTsSZN0UxJo2a6yIF4)

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Download the `Full Profile` version of `Glassfish` and not the `web` version. Here is the [link](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html) to download.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your classes are not compiling under default build/classes directory.

Do either of the following: Right click on your project > Build Project. or Go to eclipse menu > Project > Build Automatically

Now redeploy your application again. webservices Engine should be visible along with web engine.

go through below link it might help you,
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gbixz/index.html

**if you have 'Web Profile' version of GlassFish then Download the 'Full Profile' version of glassfish.**

Comment: Thank u. But I checked the target folder in my project and I saw Add.class over there. So wha do u think about that? Also how should I know I have a full version of glassfish?

Comment: I use the following version of glass fish: https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Comment: in the given link https://glassfish.java.net/download.html use the "Java EE 7 Full Platform"